# Ubuntu remove .libPaths() in R

Tags: r, linux

After I installed RStudio, I ran:

```
library()
```

> Warning message:
>       libraries '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library', 'usr/lib/R/site-library' contain no packages

Then I input:

```
.libPaths()

[1] "/home/avalon/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gun-library/3.2"
[2] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"
[4] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

How can I remove [2] and [3] to prevent the warning message appear again?

Expected output:

```
.libPaths()

[1] "/home/avalon/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gun-library/3.2"
[4] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

Comment: Remove the empty directories /usr/local/lib/R/site-library, /usr/lib/R/site-library ?

Comment: I removed them by Linux command line, but is there any problem afterward ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Linux

First thing to do is read the manpage on it (`?.libPaths`), and you'll see:

> '.libPaths' is used for getting or setting the library trees that R knows about (and hence uses when looking for packages).  If called with argument ‘new’, the library search path is set to the existing directories in **`unique(c(new, .Library.site, .Library))`** and this is returned.  If given no argument, a character vector with the currently active library trees is returned.

(emphasis added). This should clue us in to wonder what `.Library.site` holds. Oddly enough, it holds system-wide (ergo "site") library paths that "should" always be kept, so they are always maintained.

It further goes on to say:

> '.Library.site' can be set via the environment variable 'R_LIBS_SITE' (as a non-empty semicolon-separated list of library trees).

So one way to fix it is to give it an empty string ***when you start R*** (cannot be done from within R):

```
# in bash on the command line:
$ R_LIBS_SITE=" " R

# in R
R> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

The way to get this to work with RStudio is by creating a `~/.Renviron` file with at least the following:

```
R_LIBS_SITE=" "
```

That done, you should not have to do anything further to remove the secondary site library paths from `.libPaths()`:

```
R> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

### Windows

Assuming you're doing the following:

```
R> .libPaths(c("/home/avalon/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gun-library/3.2", .libPaths()))
[1] "/home/avalon/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gun-library/3.2"
[2] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"
[4] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

If you want to correct it after you've done this, then just do:

```
R> .libPaths( c(.libPaths()[c(1,4)]) )
[1] "/home/avalon/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gun-library/3.2"
[2] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

Alternatively, you can do it this way *the first time* (i.e., while it still has three elements, two of which are not good for you):

```
R> .libPaths(c("/home/avalon/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gun-library/3.2", .libPaths()[3]))
[1] "/home/avalon/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gun-library/3.2"
[2] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

There is certainly a way to filter the paths programmatically instead of blindly taking the 3rd element, but this should work for now.

Comment: Error in .libPaths("/home/avalon/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gun-library/3.2", .libPaths()):  unused argument (.libPaths())

Comment: see my edit, thanks (hasty typing) ... but I wish it worked transparently as I first typed it

Comment: still appear four options and still have Warning message: libraries '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library', 'usr/lib/R/site-library' contain no packages

Comment: actually I don't want to see the warning message , thats why I want to remove two of them

Comment: Just curious, the warning is completely cosmetic for you here, there is no harm being done. Is it enough to just `suppressWarnings(library())`?

Comment: yes, that is a good idea, but it doesn't solve the question. I installed the R and R studio before in Mac, it didn't has this problem. So actually, I would like to know why and how to fix it